# ReactJS: Function called in useEffect creates infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am building a web app that shows a visualization of different sorting algorithms. My `quickSort` function nested inside my useEffect hook is supposed to be called only once, but instead it creates an infinite loop where `quickSort` keeps getting called. I can't take the code inside `quickSort` out of its function and directly insert it into my useEffect hook because I need `quickSort` to be called recursively. How would I prevent this infinite loop from occuring?

**quick-sort.tsx**

```
import { useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { arrContext } from '../arr-context-provider';
import Visualizer from "../visualizer";

const QuickSort: React.FC = () => {
  const [arr, setArr] = useContext<[number[], React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number[]>>]>(arrContext);
  console.log("Quick Sort");

  useEffect(() => {
    quickSort(arr);
  }, []);

  const quickSort = (arr: number[], left = 0, right = arr.length - 1) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setArr(arr => {
          if (left >= right) {
            return [...arr.slice()];
          }
        
          let pivotIndex = partition(arr, left, right);
          quickSort(arr, left, pivotIndex - 1);
          quickSort(arr, pivotIndex + 1, right);
        
          return [...arr.slice()];
        });
      }, 100 * (i + 1));
    }
  }
  
  const partition = (arr: number[], left: number, right: number) => {
    let pivotValue = arr[right];
    let partitionIndex = left;
  
    for (let i = left; i < right; i++) {
      if (arr[i] < pivotValue) {
        swap(arr, i, partitionIndex);
        partitionIndex++;
      }
    }
  
    swap(arr, right, partitionIndex);
    return partitionIndex;
  }
  
  const swap = (arr: number[], firstIndex: number, secondIndex: number) => {
    let temp = arr[firstIndex];
    arr[firstIndex] = arr[secondIndex];
    arr[secondIndex] = temp;
  }

  return <Visualizer />
}

export default QuickSort;
```

Comment: are you setting state to a function that itself sets a state?
to make sure it is not the function's fault i would suggest to call it from a callback like onClick first to see it is working.

in my opinion you should probably set state only the returned values and not the whole logic.

Comment: No, the `QuickSort` component isn't inside a `setArr` function, the state of `arr` is only changing inside the `setArr` function shown here. I tried taking your suggestion by only wrapping the `setArr` function around `arr` from within the `quickSort` function, and even though this worked, it sorted the array instantly, which is not what I want. I want it to show every step that the algorithm takes. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: Could you create a live example ?